# UnassignedReferenceException: Event after assigning?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm an experienced programmer learning Unity for the first time. I know this is the most basic and common error for the newbies. I think I have got it right but it still produces this error. What am I doing wrong?

UnassignedReferenceException: The variable player of 'GameManager' has not been assigned. You probably need to assign the player variable of the GameManager script in the inspector.

I think the following screenshot provides everything needed.

[image]

Comment: which Game object in the hierarchy panel has GameManager.cs Script Component.

Comment: @SheheryarAamir Hey thanks, it was the 'Main Camera' object and that pointed me to the fix. I'm a little confused here now though. What's the purpose of assigning the player prefab object twice at two different places like this to the same variable? As far as I'm concerned the 'GameManager' class already knows what prefab it should refer to.

Comment: You've to assign game object in the hierarchy panel to any script always.
Mark my answer
thanks

Comment: Not entirely clear but ok thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to assign Game Asset in the hierarchy panel to the game object which has GameManager.cs Script Component

Answer (score 0):

I too am new to Unity and had a similar problem, but after thinking about what was going on I came to the conclusion that the error message was misleading me a bit. When it tried to be helpful by suggesting *"You probably need to assign the player variable of the GameManager script in the inspector"* I went straight to the script and set it but the error persisted.

It was then that I realised that I didn't have an object in the Hierarchy panal which had my script attached. What I was doing was instantiating an object (my 'player' prefab) at runtime and it was the prefab that had the script attached. Of course, my script might be added to any number of objects and each object will have its own variables, so each object needs to have its own instances of its variables set. If you wanted the same value to be set in all instances you probably make your variable static but it won't then appear in the inspector. So, setting the variable in the Script component of my prefab fixed it for me.

I think that's enough waffle for one day - hope it helps somebody! :)